# Jackson Feature ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY would not work with annotation

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I want to be able to call my api with POST content

```
{
  "property1" : "value1",
  "property2" : "value2"
}
```

OR

```
[{
  "property1" : "value1",
  "property2" : "value2"
}]
```

For this I annotated the java class with

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)

public class MyClass {



    private String porperty1;
    private String property2;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public MyClass(String porperty1, String property2) {
        super();
        this.porperty1 = porperty1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }


    public String getPorperty1() {
        return porperty1;
    }


    public void setPorperty1(String porperty1) {
        this.porperty1 = porperty1;
    }


    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }


    public void setProperty2(String property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

}
```

Inside the servlet I have an api like this

```
Response myAPI(Collection<MyClass> reqs, @Context HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {

}
```

But I keep getting Internal server error 500 with the 1st request type.

I have tried with updating the jackson=annotations version from 2.6.0 to 2.7.0, but it doesn't seem to be working in any.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: I have other jackson dependencies in my POM e.g. jackson-databind and jackson-core, which are still pointing to 2.6.4 (and jackson-dataformat-xml pointing to 2.6.3).  I could not update the versions of these. Would that have any issues considering I am trying jackson-annotations with higher versions?

Comment: jackson-databind contains the implementations of the annotation configurations. Updating the jackson-annotations artifact alone will not help you. It is possible that this configuration was not implemented to work at the Type level; I’ll have to look through the code if I get some time.

Comment: Okay, even after updating "jackson-databind" to 2.7, I still see the same error.  For req#2 everything works but req#1, I get HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of jackson? That would be 2.9.2. If the issue persists at that version, then I would have to assume that this configuration has not been implemented to work at the Type level. Why not open an issue on the Github repo for jackson-databind?

Comment: hmm. I can try that.  Thanks @jjones.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use that annotation on actual property, not the POJO that contains property.

Comment: But what if I need to take the whole object as a collection (or as a single value)?  Do I have create a new class and make MyClass a property of that class and then annotate it?

ps: I tried this approach too, that is wrapping MyClass inside another class and annotating that property.  But even doing that wouldn't fix it!  Somehow I think I am wrong with the version's of these Jackson API's.  I think even 2.7 wouldn't support it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you mean that the "root value" (value at top of object graph, one you are trying to deserialize), then this feature can not be used at all. It only works for properties.